# Testing with Embeded stub/dummy application in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to write a integration test for my SpringBoot microservice that interacts with another service inside the product ecosystem.
Since this kind of testing is consider function/integration testing (depending on what nomenclature you use) it is usually done on some development environment.
However, I wanted to test a basic interaction between my service and a STUB/dummy app which are connected with RPC (so not exactly a typical TestRestTemplate test).
I know that there is a way to embed a service while booting up the Spring Context but have never done it by myself.
Does anyone have any experience with the upper or maybe a few helpful links where I can explore.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) in tests to mock services external to what I want to test that communicate over HTTP.
My test class annotated with @SpringBootTest is also annotated with @ContextConfiguration. In the *classes* attribute @ContextConfiguration I explicitly specify the configuration classes required to set up the Spring Context for the test in question. Here I can also include additional configuration classes in which I create beans only used in the test. In test configuration classes I can also override beans for the purpose of the test, creating mock beans etc.
Note that Spring Boot 2.1 and later disables bean overriding by default. It can be enabled by setting the following property to true:
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
To set the property for a single test, use the @TestPropertySource annotation like this:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"
})
```